# Why can't I dynamically add rows to a HTML table using JavaScript in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

In Firefox it works, in my Internet Explorer 6 or 7 it doesn't:

```
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function newLine() {
        var tdmod = document.createElement('td');
        tdmod.appendChild(document.createTextNode("dynamic"));

        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.appendChild(tdmod);

        var tt  = document.getElementById("t1");
        tt.appendChild(tr);
      }     

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="#" onclick="newLine()">newLine</a>

      <table id="t1" border="1">
        <tr>
          <td>
          static
          </td>  
        </tr>
      </table>

</body>
```

The user clicks on the link "newLine" and new rows should be added to the table.

How to make this work also in IE?

*Edit:* Thanks to the accepted answer I changed it like this and now it works:

```
  <table border="1">
   <tbody id="t1">
    <tr>
      <td>
      static
      </td>  
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: wow, a Javascript code not working in IE?

Comment: Yeah; never ever heard of that happening before. Inconceivable!

Comment: I knew the headline would somehow get your attention ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(untested) you might try appending the row to a `tbody` element, either the one that is usually created automatically or one you define yourself.

Comment: it seems to work :-) will accept the answer after the so timout

Answer (score 4):

Always put

```
<tbody>
```

in table for IE